# Minimal components for arm A9 dev board

Tags: arm, microprocessor, computer-architecture

If someone wanted to make a barebones dev board, what is needed to get an a9 processor running? Is it reasonable for a school project or will attempting to route the ddr memory and getting it functioning correctly be too difficult a project?

Comment: Without knowing how experienced you are with PCB layout and what resources you have at your disposal, this is difficult to answer.

Comment: Lets say I know nothing about PCB layout guidelines and I only have freeware available.

Comment: You don't stand a chance. Build something simpler first.

Comment: I want to make a microprocessor system which can run from external ram though a much slower speed would be acceptable. Have an alternative suggestion? I read the original low speed ddr is easier to work with then the 2/3 used by the a9. Is this right?

Comment: Why not use SDRAM and a Cortex M for starters? I recently did a design with a STM32F4xx and external SDRAM. It was entirely painless, and I don't think it would be hugely difficult for someone without prior PCB layout knowledge. You just need to do some studying on SI and general best practices

Answer (score 1):

I admire their enthusiasm for trying to make such a design as a school project. But you talk about DDR3 memory and that makes it far too complicated as a practical proposition. You might spend valuable time and costs on fixes, debugging and respins just to get the IC and memory working. That makes a big dent in the time to get whatever application you also had in mind working.

Of course, the project might be all about design and assembly of the electronics, with the application being irrelevant. But I think it's making a rod for your own back.

Just to follow on from your question...

There are a good many low-cost demo' boards containing an ARM-A9 and bulk RAM already. You might instead consider designing and making an expander board for one of these off-the-shelf demo' boards as the project. That would simplify the complexity and requirements on your board while keeping whatever application you'd imagined possible.